# AccessViolationException when calling code through DllImport

Tags: c#, c, dllimport

I'm working on building a wrapper for a win32 dll from the USPS. I've gotten the calls to work when the pointers are passed as parameters because I can allocate and free the memory before I send the value to the function. The problem is when the data is passed back in the return value as a char *.

Here is the call in the C dll I'm working with:

```
const char* z4LLkGetKeySTD(void);
```

Here is the C# code for the DLLImport call:

```
[DllImport("C:\\AMS\\zip4_w32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "z4SLNKGetVersionSTD",
     ExactSpelling = false), ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.None)]
private static extern IntPtr z4SLNKGetVersionSTD();
```

The public facing C# method for the above private call:

```
public static string z4SLNKGetVersion()
{
    IntPtr versionPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    string version;

    versionPtr = z4SLNKGetVersionSTD();
    version = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(versionPtr);
    versionPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

    return version;
}
```

The code fails sometimes on the call to z4SLNKGetVersionSTD().

I know that returning pointers to strings in C isn't the best idea but I don't have access to the code for the dll.

Comment: Looks like cdecl to me, absolute paths are dubious, function naming is iffy and ExactSpelling should be true